# запрет нажатия QPushButton дважды Qt / C++

Tags: c++, qt

создаю калькулятор и надо запретить нажатие QPushButton кнопки дважды по очереди например 
++ //
или например запретить кнопку = нажимать дважды

Comment: А добавить флажок последней нажатой кнопки?

Comment: завести булевый флажок? (и не забывать его потом сбрасывать)

Comment: покажите пример если не сложно

Comment: button->setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перехватывать нажатие QPushButton и сравнивать с последней нажатой кнопкой

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>

enum LastButton {
    BUTTON_DEFAULT,
    BUTTON_A,
    BUTTON_B,
    BUTTON_C,
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0)
        : QMainWindow(parent),
          _lastButton(BUTTON_DEFAULT)
    {

        _lineEditOut = new QLineEdit;

        _buttonA = new QPushButton("A");
        _buttonB = new QPushButton("B");
        _buttonC = new QPushButton("C");

        connect(_buttonA, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonA);
        connect(_buttonB, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonB);
        connect(_buttonC, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::onButtonC);

        connect(this, &MainWindow::buttonPressed, this, &MainWindow::onButtonPressed);


        QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
        mainLayout->addWidget(_lineEditOut);
        mainLayout->addWidget(_buttonA);
        mainLayout->addWidget(_buttonB);
        mainLayout->addWidget(_buttonC);

        QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
        widget->setLayout(mainLayout);

        this->setCentralWidget(widget);
    }

signals:
    void buttonPressed(QString);

private slots:
    void onButtonA()
    {
        if(_lastButton == LastButton::BUTTON_A) {
            // если уже нажимали такую кнопку, то ничего не делаем
            return;
        }

        emit buttonPressed("A");

        _lastButton = LastButton::BUTTON_A;
    }

    void onButtonB()
    {
        if(_lastButton == LastButton::BUTTON_B) {
            // если уже нажимали такую кнопку, то ничего не делаем
            return;
        }

        emit buttonPressed("B");

        _lastButton = LastButton::BUTTON_B;
    }

    void onButtonC()
    {
        if(_lastButton == LastButton::BUTTON_C) {
            // если уже нажимали такую кнопку, то ничего не делаем
            return;
        }

        emit buttonPressed("C");

        _lastButton = LastButton::BUTTON_C;
    }

    void onButtonPressed(QString text) {

        _lineEditOut->setText(_lineEditOut->text() + text);

    }




private:
    QPushButton* _buttonA;
    QPushButton* _buttonB;
    QPushButton* _buttonC;

    QLineEdit*   _lineEditOut;

    LastButton _lastButton;


};
```